# C# Threading and Forms: NotSupportedException - Use Control.Invoke?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, windows-mobile, backgroundworker

I am trying to run an application with at least two threads: One form for the user interface and one or more worker threads. They are jointly reading/writing from a static class through a number of other classes.

This is why I am passing an instance of the worker class to the display form. I guess that is why it goes wrong for me:

```
 public class CoCoon
 {
    private Screen displayForm;
    private Worker worker; 

    public ThreadedApp()
    {
        worker = new Worker (1024);
        displayForm = new Screen(worker);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        //thread 1: display form
        Thread screenThread = new Thread(() => Application.Run(displayForm));

        //thread 2: background worker
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(worker.Run) {IsBackground = true};

        screenThread.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(1000); //if I don't wait a while, I get an ObjectDisposedException!

        workerThread.Start();

    }
```

The threads and objects are initiated just fine, but as soon after the Form_Load method is has been handled, an error is thrown on the Application.Run(displayForm) line above. It is an NotSupportedException, with a remark that I should use Control.Invoke. But I am not sure I understand, because I am not letting threads other than the display form's use the controls on it.

I am new to threading. Can anyone help me on my way? Thanks!

PS: One detail - I am developing this for the Windows Mobile platform.

**EDIT** After popular request hereby the Stack Trace

```
 at Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr(PAL_ERROR ar)\r\n   at    
 System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Visible()\r\n   at 
 System.Windows.Forms.Form._SetVisibleNotify(Boolean fVis)\r\n   at  
 System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)\r\n   at 
 System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)\r\n   at
 CoCoonWM6.CoCoon.<Run>b__1()\r\n
```

Comment: It might help to know what the worker thread is doing.

Comment: WAG (not a win mobile dev), but why have a thread for Application.Run?    Also, `screenThread` should be STA, but you're not setting that.  Also, also, also...

Comment: Check out the stack trace for the exception (and post it). You are almost certainly accessing some Control from the worker thread.

Comment: Thanks guys. As said, I am new to threading especially with forms, so any proposals and remarks on what I forgot are welcomed.

Comment: I cannot tell from the Stack Trace how the other thread is accessing the UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you only have one UI thread, the main thread. You can use your other threads for background operations, but keep all UI stuff on the main thread.

The UI thread should be the only one calling `Application.Run`. WinForms has other requirements for the UI thread (such as being STA), and those are satisfied by the main thread. In theory, it may be possible for WinForms to support two UI threads, but it's certainly not easy.

I normally recommend other forms of synchronization when you need to update UI controls from a background thread - `TaskScheduler` or `SynchronizationContext`. On the mobile platform, unfortunately, your only option is `Control.Invoke`.

Comment: Thanks. That actually sounds like an interesting option. I will try something in that direction.

Comment: This actually led me on the right track. I had been doing it like this all along in a previous version of the code. I just got the impression that the form was waiting for the other thread to finish, which is why I thought I had to put that on another thread too. After reverting to the previous version and doing some testing it turned out I was mistaken. So now it works as I want to after all! :-D

Answer (score 1):

Check out the stack trace for the exception (and post it). You are almost certainly accessing some `Control` from the worker thread.

This is how you can modify access to a Control (in this example a Label) after you find where you are accessing controls from non-UI threads:

```
if (label13.InvokeRequired)
{
  ChangeTextDelegate changeText = new ChangeTextDelegate(anyChangeTextMethod);
  label13.Invoke(changeText, new object[] { newText });
}
else
{
  label13.Text = newText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I cannot tell from the Stack Trace how the other thread is accessing the UI thread.

Comment: I guess you are instantiating `displayForm` on another thread than `screenThread`, right? You have to instantiate `displayForm` on the same thread on what you access it unless you want to wrap everything via `Invoke`! The best option would be to use the main thread. You can start the worker thread first and let it wait for `displayForm`'s command to "really start".

Comment: Ah, what goes wrong, I think, is that I both run the form AND try to start it in a new thread, whereas I could just suffice with instantiate the worker thread and leave the form be, as it is running already automatically in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to use GUI elements in the background thread. That would explain why you have to call `Sleep` (otherwise the form and its controls don't finish loading before you try to use them) as well as the `Control.Invoke` exception (you can't use GUI elements from a non-UI thread). See the docs for [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) for how you should use it.

Since you don't have `BackgroundWorker` and `Px` in the CF, you're indeed forced to use threads directly - though the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) would probably be better than instantiating new threads, most of the time.